# PHP array_walk doesn't change the array's values

Tags: php

I have this simple code:

```
$postCopy = $_POST['adminpanel'];
array_walk($postCopy, function($v, $k) {
    return '';
});
```

I did `var_dump` for `postCopy` before and after `array_walk` execution.
In both `var_dump` executions, I get the same result:

```
array(2) { ["usefulinfo_countryfilescount"]=> string(1) "3" ["strageticoverviews_filesinpagecount"]=> string(1) "3" }
```

So it means that `array_walk` didn't execute correctly, because if it would- I'd get an array with `''` values...

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot to pass argument by reference :

```
$postCopy = $_POST['adminpanel'];
array_walk($postCopy, function(&$v, $k) {
    $v = '';
});
```

Comment: Nice edit, it still doesn't work, because the return value of the callback is not used.

Comment: Yep i just reverse position of reference argument, that were i made an mistake.
To use it only edit variable `$v` to give it an new value.

Answer (score 2):

From [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

> **Note**:
>
> If `callback` needs to be working with the actual values of the array, specify the first parameter of `callback` as a [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php). Then, any changes made to those elements will be made in the original array itself.

So you need to change your call to:

```php
array_walk($postCopy, function(&$v, $k) {
  $v = "";
});
```

Note the `&` in the argument list. The return value of `callback` is not actually used.

Also, consider using [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), if you are modifying all elements of an array.